# How to check if Strings are in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

example:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
```

how to check if `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` are in array?

i tried `indexOf()` but i cant check if more than 1 strings are in array...

Comment: Did you consider using a "loop"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are use [`Array.protoype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), like this

```
["a", "b", "c"].every(function(currentItem) {
    return arr.indexOf(currentItem) !== -1;
});
```

This will return `true`, only if all the elements in `["a", "b", "c"]` are present in `arr`.

Comment: will it be true if there are other strings too in that array?

Comment: @IrakliBerberashvili What do you mean by that? Can you give an example?

Comment: In which browsers is this compatible?

Comment: @Seabiscuit Do you want me to include the list of browsers which do not support these functions?

Comment: At least the earliest iteration of IE browsers that support them. That's usually the bottleneck

Comment: @Seabiscuit We [discussed this in meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276121/1903116). So, I feel that I don't have to mention the compatibility information here.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
var arr1=['a','b','c'];
     for(i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
         var a1 = arr.indexOf(arr1[i]);
            console.log(a1);
     }
```

or

```
var a = arr.indexOf("a");
console.log(a);//0
var b = arr.indexOf("b");
console.log(b);//1
var c = arr.indexOf("c");
console.log(c);//2
```